# Gatsby Error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'PageProps<object, object, unknown>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, gatsby

I recently updated Gatsby from version 2.X to 3.X and have run into quite a bit of errors. I'm using TypeScript, but this is my first time using `PageProps`. However, I'm getting an error and I'm assuming its from `PageProps` not being passed to `Home` in the `index.tsx` component. Can someone clarify this for me?

**Error:**

```js
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'PageProps<object, object, unknown>': path, uri, location, navigate, and 5 more.ts(2740)
```

**index.tsx**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { PageProps } from 'gatsby';

// Imports: Pages
import Home from './Home';

// Imports: Components
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout';

// Index
const index: React.FC<PageProps> = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    // <Layout>
      <Home /> // ERROR IS HERE
    // </Layout>
  );
};

// Exports
export default index;
```

**Home.tsx:**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { PageProps } from 'gatsby';

// Imports: Components
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

// Page: Home
const Home: React.FC<PageProps> = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Container id="home-container">
      <NavBar />

      <Hero />

      <Footer />
    </Container>
  );
};

// Exports
export default Home;
```

Comment: I don't have experience with gatsby, but in reactjs with typescript, you don't need to do this React.FC<PageProps>, this should be used whenever you want to drill/pass props to component.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { PageProps } from 'gatsby';
// Imports: Components
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

// Page: Home
const Home= (props: PageProps) => {
  return (
    <Container id="home-container">
      <NavBar />

      <Hero />

      <Footer />
    </Container>
  );
};

// Exports
export default Home;
```

In this case, you don't need to pass props to a component so you can avoid the offending line:

```
const Home: React.FC<PageProps> = (): JSX.Element => {
```

More details at: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/typescript/